# How does the Predict function handle continuous values with a 0 in R for a Poisson Log Link Model?

Tags: r, offset, glm, predict, poisson

I am using a Poisson GLM on some dummy data to predict ClaimCounts based on two variables, frequency and Judicial Orientation.

Dummy Data Frame:

```
data5 <-data.frame(Year=c("2006","2006","2006","2007","2007","2007","2008","2009","2010","2010","2009","2009"), 
           JudicialOrientation=c("Defense","Plaintiff","Plaintiff","Neutral","Defense","Plaintiff","Defense","Plaintiff","Neutral","Neutral","Plaintiff","Defense"),
           Frequency=c(0.0,0.06,.07,.04,.03,.02,0,.1,.09,.08,.11,0),
           ClaimCount=c(0,5,10,3,4,0,7,8,15,16,17,12),
           Loss = c(100000,100,2500,100000,25000,0,7500,5200, 900,100,0,50),
           Exposure=c(10,20,30,1,2,4,3,2,1,54,12,13)
           )
```

Model GLM:

```
ClaimModel <- glm(ClaimCount~JudicialOrientation+Frequency     
                           ,family = poisson(link="log"), offset=log(Exposure), data = data5, na.action=na.pass)

Call:
glm(formula = ClaimCount ~ JudicialOrientation + Frequency, family = poisson(link = "log"), 
    data = data5, na.action = na.pass, offset = log(Exposure))

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-3.7555  -0.7277  -0.1196   2.6895   7.4768  

Coefficients:
                             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                   -0.3493     0.2125  -1.644      0.1    
JudicialOrientationNeutral    -3.3343     0.5664  -5.887 3.94e-09 ***
JudicialOrientationPlaintiff  -3.4512     0.6337  -5.446 5.15e-08 ***
Frequency                     39.8765     6.7255   5.929 3.04e-09 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 149.72  on 11  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 111.59  on  8  degrees of freedom
AIC: 159.43

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 6
```

I am using an offset of Exposure as well.

I then want to use this GLM to predict claim counts for the same observations:

```
data5$ExpClaimCount <- predict(ClaimModel, newdata=data5, type="response")
```

If I understand correctly then the Poisson glm equation should then be:

> ClaimCount = exp(-.3493 + -3.3343*JudicialOrientationNeutral +
>   -3.4512*JudicialOrientationPlaintiff + 39.8765*Frequency + log(Exposure))

However I tried this manually`(In excel =EXP(-0.3493+0+0+LOG(10)) for observation 1 for example)` and for some of the observations but did not get the correct answer.

Is my understanding of the GLM equation incorrect?

Comment: You're probably seeing different results because `LOG` in Excel is base 10 logarithm. Try using `LN` instead.

Comment: @tkmckenzie Excatlyl in R it is `log(x, base = exp(1))` for default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right with the assumption about how `predict()` for a Poisson GLM works. This can be verified in R:

```
co <- coef(ClaimModel)
p1 <- with(data5,
           exp(log(Exposure) +                            # offset
               co[1] +                                    # intercept
               ifelse(as.numeric(JudicialOrientation)>1,  # factor term
                      co[as.numeric(JudicialOrientation)], 0) +
               Frequency * co[4]))                        # linear term

all.equal(p1, predict(ClaimModel, type="response"), check.names=FALSE)
[1] TRUE
```

As indicated in the comments you probably get the wrong results in Excel because of the different basis of the logarithm (10 in Excel, Euler's number in R).

Comment: That explains it. Thank you. This small detail I was not aware of but this helps me immensely. Thanks!